# Get the related search queries using sunspot solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

My rails application using sunspot solr to search the books/authors. Now If I give search query as

> "Jeffrey Archer"

it ll give the set of books which has "jeffrey archer" as author. But If I give

> "Jefrey Archer"

sunspot doesn't return any results. So that time I want to show

> did you mean? "jeffrey archer"

How to implement this using sunpspot solr ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spellcheck integration into Sunspot is experimental: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/tree/spellcheck

I have not been very satisfied with the results that I've been able to achieve with spellcheck in Solr 1.4 and 3.x. However, with the release of Solr 4.0 and its improved spellcheck functionality, it's something that's due to be revisited.

You can try the branch I've linked, alternately you may want to use RSolr directly to execute your own spellcheck requests directly.

Pull requests welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Solr provides a [Spell Check Component](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent) using which you can provide Spell correction to the user based on the terms in your index.
Sunspot is just a CLient, so you just need to check how you configure Spell Check Component.